# Are level 20 Druids essentially unkillable?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, druid, wild-shape

So maybe I'm reading this wrong, but my moon druid just hit level 20 and the ability seems completely over the top compared to other classes level 20 feature. Unlimited beast shapes? Am I interpreting this incorrectly? Can I really just turn into animals or even elementals (Level 10 Elemental Wild shape) AND EVEN CAST SPELLS (Level 18 Beast spell) ??

My DM for this game hates this and is trying to limit my uses to 10 per long rest, which is fine, but without this homebrew rule in place can I just make myself a meat shield and keep beast shaping into something with massive HP (e.g A giant crocodile) or even an Earth elemental every time I pop?

Comment: Related: [Are Moon Druids overpowered at levels 2-6? If so, by how much?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136373/33707) and [Does unlimited Wild Shape make Circle of the Moon archdruids virtually unkillable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70392/33707)

Comment: Might want to drop into [chat].  The problem with encounters at level 20 with monsters that atr CR 21+ is that it takes quite a bit of DM tinkering to work.  Asking "is this broken" is often a matter of opinion, and this format does not do opinion based questions.

Comment: Power Word Kill is the bane of high level shapeshifters.

Comment: @JRodge01: It's also the bane of basically every lower HP class (Wizard/Sorcerer with +2 Con mod only has 122 HP at level 20 after all), so that's not saying much.